# Spring framework repository query returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am working on a code making currency conversion.

I have the following repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface FxRateRepository extends JpaRepository<FxRate,Long> {

    List<FxRate> findByCurrencyCode(String currencyTo, String currencyFrom);
```

And the following DB records:

[image]

The scenario is that there is an incoming amoint of money in EUR and i want to save it in a bank account in USD. To make so, I have to convert based on the current changing rates.

I have the follwing  code snippet:

```
 private BigDecimal getAmount(AccountData accountData, Input input) {
    String currencyOfAccount = accountData.getCurrency();
    String amountCurrency = input.getCurrency();

    List<FxRate> res = fxRateRepository.findByCurrencyCode(currencyOfAccount, amountCurrency);
    if (Objects.nonNull(res)) {
        for (FxRate fxRate : res) {
            if (amountCurrency.equals(currencyOfAccount)) {
                return inputAmount;
            } else if (currencyOfAccount.equals("HUF")) {
                BigDecimal midPrice = getMidPriceBasedOnAmountCurrency(input, fxRate);
                if (Objects.nonNull(midPrice)) {
                    return inputAmount.multiply(midPrice)
                            .setScale(5, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
                }
            } else if (!currencyOfAccount.equals("HUF")) {
                BigDecimal midPriceBasedOnCurrencyOfAccount = getMidPriceBasedOnCurrencyOfAccount(accountData, fxRate);
                if (Objects.nonNull(midPriceBasedOnAmountCurrency) && Objects.nonNull(midPriceBasedOnCurrencyOfAccount)) {
                    return inputAmount.multiply(midPrice).divide(midPriceBasedOnCurrencyOfAccount)
                            .setScale(5, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And the following method to get the midPrice and this is the one which returns constantly null value:

```
private BigDecimal getMidPriceBasedOnAmountCurrency(Input input, FxRate fxRate) {
    if (fxRate.getCurrencyCode().equals(input.getCurrency())) {
        return fxRate.getMidPrice();
    } else if (input.getCurrency().equals(fxRate.getFixingCurrencyCode())) {
        return new BigDecimal("0");
    } else if (!input.getCurrency().equals(fxRate.getCurrencyCode()) && !input.getCurrency().equals(fxRate.getFixingCurrencyCode())){
       BigDecimal midPrice = fxRateRepository.findMidPrice(input.getCurrency());
       return midPrice;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which is based on....:

```
@Query("SELECT fx.midPrice FROM FxRate fx WHERE fx.currencyCode =:currencyTo")
    BigDecimal findMidPrice(@Param("currencyTo") String currencyTo);
```

This query gives me constantly null althouh the currencyTo is replaced successfully to EUR but the DB record is not found...

I also tried with a list search:

```
List<FxRate> findMidPrice(String currencyTo);
```

... and then get the field with :

```
List<FxRate> midPriceList = fxRateRepository.findMidPrice(amountCurrency);
BigDecimal midPrice = midPriceList.get(0).getMidPrice();
```

Gives null too...

I cannot get why it does not return the correct value althouh it worked with the findByCurrencyCode like a charm....

Any idea?

---

UPDATE

If I put the second query to a separate new class / repository, then it is working...

Comment: What you posted doesn't make sense. The find method in Spring Data JPA won't work unless you specify a query or have a named query for it. Next your `findMidPrice` is also wrong as you are querying the full `FxRate` but expect a `BigDecimal`. So either this isn't the code you are actually using or you are really running code that doesn't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah, I copied my query wrong, but was actually correct in my code. It is looking for a BigDecimal indeed.. I have updated my code in the above question

Comment: As Deinum pointed out "The find method in Spring Data JPA won't work unless you specify a query or have a named query for it", your example is still not clear

Comment: This method should work in JPA repository `List<FxRate> findByCurrencyCode(String currencyCode);`